# Campo no requerido con Auth - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, auth, required

Tengo un register hecho con Auth en Laravel 8, he añadido un campo "surnames" y me lo pone requerido por defecto cuando en en la función no le he puesto "required", (El input del HTML tampoco tiene el required)

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'rol' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],     
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],

            'surnames' => ['string', 'max:255'] /*CAMPO SURNAMES*/
            
        ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'rol' => $data['rol'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

            'surnames' => $data['surnames'] /*CAMPO SURNAMES*/
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Si es cuando lo mandas, deberías ver tu HTML haber si allí lo pusiste requerido, ahora si no también podrías ver si es un campo obligatorio en tu BD.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo estás dejando como opcional, a la hora de hacer el submit y no tener valor, `validator` tomará su valor `nulo` como inválido.
Para evitar esto agrega la regla `nullable`.

```php
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
    'publish_at' => 'nullable|date',
]);
```

> ... a menudo necesitarás marcar tus campos opcionales como `nullable` si no quieres que `validator` considere los valores `null` como inválidos.
> [Laravel 8 Validation: A note on optional fields](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)